# What is the difference between "loquacious" and "talkative"?

Tags: differences, synonyms

What is the different between *loquacious* and *talkative*? I don't see much different in their definition:

> **Loquacious**: tending to talk a great deal; talkative.
>   **Talkative**: fond of or given to talking.

Regarding [M-W Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loquacious), they are different as follow:

> *Talkative* may imply a readiness to engage in talk or a disposition to enjoy conversation .
>   *Loquacious* suggests the power of expressing oneself articulately, fluently, or glibly

But I don't see the different. Isn't that anyone who is talkative is also having an ability to talk fluently, therefore matching the description of *talkative*? Is it true that *loquacious* has the same meaning of *talkative*?

Comment: The number of people who know what *loquacious* means is very much smaller than the number who know what *talkative* means.

Comment: The definition that you listed for *loquatious* quite clearly states that it is identical in meaning to *talkative*. Your word choice would depend on the audience.

Comment: There are no exact synonyms. There are instances where you could use one but definitely not the other.

Comment: I would tend to imagine a "loquacious" person as being a bit flamboyant in his speech patterns, whereas a "talkative" person simply talks a lot.  But I have no idea whether others would view it the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one has yet addressed your question about the *Merriam-Webster's* explanation, I will.

To repeat, the *Merriam-Webster* says this:

> *talkative, loquacious, garrulous, voluble* mean given to talk or talking.
> *talkative* may imply a readiness to engage in talk or a disposition to enjoy conversation.
>
> > a talkative neighbor
>
> *loquacious* suggests the power of expressing oneself articulately, fluently, or glibly.
>
> > a loquacious spokesperson

Then you ask,

> But I don't see the difference. Isn't it the case that anyone who is talkative also has the ability to talk fluently, therefore matching the description of *talkative*? Is it true that *loquacious* has the same meaning of *talkative*?

Well, no.

It is perfectly possible for there to be a person who tends to enjoys conversation (so is *talkative*) but who has no power to express themselves either articulately, or fluently, or glibly (and so is not *loquacious*). In fact, I'd wager that most of us *know* people like that! They jump at every chance to strike up a conversation, but are by no means *skilled* at expressing themselves, and we may have trouble understanding half of what they are trying to say.

Conversely, it is also possible that someone is very articulate (or fluent or glib) when talking, but who actually usually doesn't talk to people for mere enjoyment of conversation. On the contrary, this person usually approaches people with a particular goal in mind, such as convincing them to support some cause or participate in some action or form a certain belief. Such a person we wouldn't necessarily call *talkative,* but we might call them *loquacious*.

Answer (score 1):

They are essentially synonyms, the following extract suggests that loquacious has a more negative connotation than talkative and is less common as shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talkative%2C%20loquacious&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctalkative%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cloquacious%3B%2Cc0):

Talkative:

> - Our starting word, “talkative,” should describe somebody who likes to talk frequently or at length. Interestingly, talkative can be used with either a positive or negative connotation, but, for the most part, it’s a fairly positive word. I could say “My talkative friend easily navigates from conversation to conversation;” here, the word “talkative” suggests my friend is a facile communicator. Conversely, I could say “After only one drink, Suzie became very talkative;” here, the word has a gently negative connotation.

Loquacious:

> - Loquacious implies an inclination to talk incessantly or to keep up a constant flow of chatter. For example, “John, a loquacious investment banker, never tired of exhausting his dinner guests with self-indulgent chatter.” Notice that loquacious doesn’t have the versatility that talkative has–it’s always negative. For that reason, it’s a more precise word.

[grockit.com/blog/vocabulary](http://grockit.com/blog/vocabulary-usage/)

Comment: I would disagree that talkative is positive. It's at best, neutral.

Comment: Since "loquacious" is an uncommon word, even people who more or less know its meaning might not be aware of any positive or negative connotations. In fact its apparent similarity to "eloquent" might even impart a positive connotation to some. "Talkative" is neutral or negative to me, and I would use something like "outgoing" instead to refer to such a person in a positive way.

Comment: @ghostarbeiter - less common probably, but not as uncommon as you suggest. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=loquacious%2C+talkative&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cloquacious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalkative%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

From Dictionary.com:

Talkative, garrulous, loquacious characterize a person who talks a great deal. Talkative is a neutral or mildly unfavorable word applied to a person who is inclined to talk a great deal, sometimes without significance: a talkative child.The garrulous person talks with wearisome persistence, usually about personal and trivial things: a garrulous old man.A loquacious person, intending to be sociable, talks continuously and at length: a loquacious host.

As Hack Saw says, talkative is not generally positive.  It is, in my opinion, unfavorable more often than neutral, especially from my point of view as a teacher.

And of course, you must consider that talkative will be understood by far more people than loquacious will.

Comment: In your example of a loquacious host, can you describe more detail about them? For example, are they talking in the way that annoying the audience? Is *loquacious* a negative word?

Comment: Loquacious is not generally thought of as negative.  A loquacious speaker is one who is comfortable with words, and uses them effectively.  It can connote someone who talks to excess, which might be annoying, but I don't think it is built into the meaning of the word.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the main difference is in their delivery; perhaps you could say the "quality" of the speaker's word choices or sentences. For example, a "talkative" person would be one whose speaks simply, and uses more common terminology or better known synonyms.  A "loquacious" speaker would use lesser known terms, "fancier" pronunciations (think 'vahz' rather than 'vase') or words that most people haven't seen since they studied for the SAT.  A "garrulous" person speaks frequently, but seldom has anything positive or upbeat to contribute...a talkative "Debbie Downer" if you will.

Comment: Hello, Annie. On ELU, 'answers' that come across as (or are) opinion, usually because they lack supporting evidence, are not usually all that helpful. Check the other 'answers' (and Katherine Lockwood's 'comment').

Comment: I don't think pronouncing *vase* as *vahz* is "fancy", it's the normal way to pronounce it where I live.

Answer (score 0):

A talkative person talks a lot but, a loquacious person talks with more details and are animated to paint a visual picture for their audience to create emotion.

Comment: Welcome to ELU Stack Exchange, and thanks for posting an answer. Your answer could be improved by providing references with links for context. Otherwise, you are stating an opinion based on your personal knowledge. Please refer to the help topic http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for tips about providing the best possible answers.